# Нужна ли запятая в предложении? И как это грамотно объяснить?

Tags: пунктуация

Доверительный платеж — это услуга, позволяющая Вам восстановить доступ к сети Интернет(,) если на счету закончились деньги.

Answer (score 2):

Запятая нужна. Во-первых, в этом месте заканчивается обособленный причастный оборот *позволяющая Вам восстановить доступ к сети Интернет*, а во-вторых, здесь начинается придаточное предложение *если на счету закончились деньги*.